# ajaxSubmit not working in IE jQuery Form plugin

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, compatibility

I am using jQuery form plugin to upload images in my MVC project.

For some reason the Code in IE no longer working (worked before):
I can tell the submit is successful, image is successful uploaded, and recoded in database, however the response seems somehow corrupted in IE.

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            AddImage(responseText.ImageId);
            buildArray();
        }
```

I tested on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, it all working fine, however when i use it in IE.

I got error:

> Message: 'ImageId' is null or not an
>   object

Anyone have had any similar problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might want to check my answer here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425231/ajaxsubmit-and-internet-explorer-issue/20022629#20022629][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425231/ajaxsubmit-and-internet-explorer-issue/20022629#20022629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem solved by changing the content type from "text/plain" to "text/html", that's it.

OMFG, Internet Explore!

Code I have changed:

```
return Json(newImage, "text/html", Encoding.Unicode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

hope that would help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation about File Uploads:

*It is important to note that even when the dataType option is set to 'script', and the server is actually responding with some javascript to a multipart form submission, the response's Content-Type header should be forced to text/html, otherwise Internet Explorer will prompt the user to download a "file".*

I don't know it worked before, but the documentation is clear about this concern.